# Overriding and Hiding Methods

Tags: java, overriding

I´m learning Java using the tutorial in Oracle Page.

Thanks,

```
public class Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("The static method in Animal");
        }
        public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance method in Animal");
        }
    }

    public class Cat extends Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("The static method in Cat");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance method in Cat");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat myCat = new Cat();
        Animal myAnimal = myCat;
        Animal.testClassMethod();
        myAnimal.testInstanceMethod();
    }
}
```

Can anybody, explain me what is the meaning of the statement:

Animal myAnimal = myCat;

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe if you actually ran the code you'd understand from the console output.

Comment: What do **you** think it means? Give us your best guess.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to familiarize yourself with the Stack Overflow [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help), which will help you understand what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site. This site is intended to help you obtain answers to *specific programming questions*, as opposed to providing tutorial assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`Cat` extends `Animal`, right? So, every `Cat` IS-A `Animal`. That means, that every instance of `Cat` is also instance of `Animal`. Therefore, you can assign `myCat` to the variable `myAnimal`, which is of type `Animal`.